# Issues with compiling perl script into executable

Tags: perl, perlapp

I am trying to compile the perlscript below using activestate perlapp. I dont think it has anything to do with the PerlApp program. It runs fine when I just debug and run through activestate

this is the error when I try to compile it into an executable file.

Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (@INC contains:) at (eval 38) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 38) line 2.
 at twittertest.pl line 3

Here is the short code:

```
use Net::Twitter::Lite;

my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(
      traits   => [qw/OAuth API::REST/],
  consumer_key        => 'PEA',
  consumer_secret     => 'M6tDj7MFsuqeyxjOYhzFJR8',
  access_token        => '460868284-oMUErVuM86yT2Q38LAspU3',
  access_token_secret => 'gteAqdgthMjMVtE8'
);

  my $result = $nt->update('Hopefully One Final App Test!');
```

Comment: and the access numbers and token numbers are not the correct ones so this wont work if you just copy and paste it. I am just not sure what the error is caused from

Comment: Did you use the `--add` parameter to PerlApp to add that module? A simple require isn't good enough...

Comment: @shinjuo: I suggest that instead of replacing your tokens with random strings, replace them with 'REDACTED', 'SEKRET', 'PASSWORD', or similar, then its immediately clear without having the read the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the Added modules container (on the Files tab) to add LWP::UserAgent module.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PerlApp expert, but this may be the solution you're looking for. From the [PerlApp overview](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlApp_overview.html):

> When requiring modules, be sure to use the **--add** option to list
>   additional modules for PerlApp to traverse. Simple require statements
>   (see below) do not contain enough information for PerlApp to load the
>   necessary module(s).
>
> require $module;